What sites are for distributed computing?
Blockchain is a kind of distributed systems. 
I was wondering what sites on the StackExchange network or on the Internet (like reddit, quora, etc) are for discussion and questions and answers for distributed computing?
Thanks.

Following sites in the Stack Exchange network would be relevant to specific discussion on the distributed computing aspects such as Consensus, Fault Tolerance, Partial Synchrony, etc.

Stack Overflow
Computer Science
Theoretical Computer Science

